# find a selector inside a ajax div

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors, datatables

i have a case, that there is 1 page that loading through ajax.load(). in that page a have a table, and i wanna use jquery DataTables. i got an ID for that table, let just say its id="table_01", and the parent is a div got a class name as "box". For the container to loading a page i use a div with id="content".

now in may script for using DataTables,

```
<script>$(document).ready(function() {
$('#table_01').DataTable(); });</script>
```

when i open that page, the page is loaded but the table is not changing. The script is not in the same file with the table. Is in the Container footer,

then i try something that doesn't use any jquery ajax load, is working. so i'm thinking the problem is with the selector. I've try to use find(), but no luck or using $('#conten #table_01').

maybe if the script is in the same file with the table, is working fine. but i don't wanna do that,

can this be done? 
Thanks for your reply, btw

Comment: [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method is async, you need to set your logic targeting any loaded content in complete callback of `load()` method, e.g: `$('.box').load('uriPath', function(){ $('#table_01').DataTable(); });`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Try this :

<script>
    $('.selector').load( "target_page.php", function() {
        $('#table_01').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

[Look here for full documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

**Edit**: Minimal code

Comment: suddenly i had another issued this morning, just to make it simple can i load that  `$('#table_01').DataTable();` outside this `<script>$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.selector').load( "target_page.php");
</script>`

can it be done?